# Explanation of a timeseries bootstrap to a layperson

Tags: time-series, bootstrap

I am trying to explain the output of a time-series bootstrap to someone who knows nothing about them. I recently learned about them myself and wanted to make sure my explanation was correct. Is this explanation correct statistically?

You can use a time-series bootstrap to estimate the chance that a certain price is reached (1.3568) **or exceeded** within 20 timepoints. Based on a random bootstrap with 100 samples I have 2.21% chance of reaching **or exceeding** the value 1.3568 within 20 timepoints.

```r
set.seed(42)
library(boot)
myfun <- function(tsb){
  data.approx <- approxfun(density(tsb))
  data.approx(newpointsX)
}
newpointsX <<- log(1.3568)
data <- sample(runif(500,1.1,1.7), 100)  # Cl(test)
# the stationary bootstrap with mean block length 20
tsboot(log(data), statistic=myfun, R=100, l=20, parallel="multicore", sim="fixed")
```

Output:

```r
> tsboot(log(data), statistic=myfun, R=100, l=20, parallel="multicore", sim="fixed")

BLOCK BOOTSTRAP FOR TIME SERIES

Fixed Block Length of 20 

Call:
tsboot(tseries = log(data), statistic = myfun, R = 100, l = 20, 
    sim = "fixed", parallel = "multicore")

Bootstrap Statistics :
    original      bias    std. error
t1* 2.215443 0.002299522   0.2373952
```

**Edits in bold are an attempt to clarify in response to comments.**

Comment: What is your rationale for the `myfun` function? It doesn't seem to account for any of the time-series structure of your data. You are getting bootstrapped standard errors for that, but it seems like a nonsensical statistic.

Comment: I had to generate a statistic for each sample, so I thought (perhaps wrongly) that the function `myfun` would calculate the percentage chance of getting the `newpointsX` value for each randomly generated sample that is created by the bootstrat

Comment: Continuously valued realizations will never achieve a specific value. Use a more intuitive `myfun` funciton, I can't make sense of `myfun(log(data))`, so bootstrapping will only make matters worse, not better.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to create the function correctly? As I mentioned in my post, I am still new at this. The current function returns (ideally) the percentage chance of hitting a specific value based on the given distribution (which may be totally backwards)

Comment: You need to ask a different question. There is a 0% chance of hitting a specific value as I said. Your function furthermore does not calculate any probability either. Are you interested in values within an $\epsilon$ window? Or any different measure of center?

Comment: Oh sorry, My goal is to predict the chance of hitting that value OR GREATER (that is the part I was missing)

Comment: I created a new question to adress the issue here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224146/how-to-bootstrap-to-get-probability-of-reaching-a-value-or-greater